# Angularjs chrome extension won't return template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been playing around with using angularjs in a  chrome extension but I have run into the issue of the template not being displayed in the extension popup. When I click the extension icon it just displays a small popup without my directive's content and no errors show up in chrome dev tools.

I've been aiming to write it in a way which will make the transition to angular2 easier in the future, hence there being no controllers.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious or what I'm doing isn't compatible with the way chrome extensions work.

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-csp>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>-->
        <script src="/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/controller.helloWorld.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="MyApp">

    <helloWorld></helloWorld>

    </body>
</html>
```

**controller.helloWorld.js**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp', []).directive('helloWorld', function() {

        function HelloCtrl() {            

        var vm = this;

        vm.hello = "";

        vm.sayHello = function() {
             vm.hello = "Hello World!"; 
            };
        }

        return {
        template: [
            '<div>',
                '<p>',
                    '{{helloWorld.hello}}',
                '</p>',                
                '<button ng-click="helloWorld.sayHello()">Say Hello</button>',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        scope: {},
        controller: HelloCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'helloWorld',
        bindToController: true
    };
});

})();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "action point manager extension",
    "description": "This extension allows users to collaborate on action point lists",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Action point manager"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Should rename that js file since it no longer uses a controller

Comment: Just in case, are you looking at the popup's devtools? It appears after you rightclick the popup and select Inspect.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing, no errors though

Comment: Have you check if you implemented angularjs in chrome correctly? See this [document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/angular_framework) gets you started building Chrome Apps with the AngularJS MVC framework.

Comment: It was an unbelievable rookie mistake all along. <helloWorld></helloWorld> should've been <hello-World></hello-World>